# Создавать ли отдельные таблицы для информации каждого пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Изучаю php, не знаю как правильно объединить систему регистрации и хранение данных каждого пользователя. Есть проект To Do List, имею на руках систему регистрации и сохранение задач, которые вводит пользователь. Каким образом можно объединить их, чтобы при регистрации либо входе на сайт, отображались только задачи определенного пользователя?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Данные то вы где храните?

Comment: Я использую XAMPP PhpMyAdmin, добавляю в одну таблицу id, user_name и pass. В другую таблицу id и текст который вводит пользователь в input

Comment: В другую таблицу (id и текст) добавляй и ИД пользователя который внес данные. Зная залогинившегося пользователя доставай только те тексты у которых ИД пользователя = ИД залогинившегоя пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо большое